# Horizontal Scroll not working with fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, horizontal-scrolling, fullpage.js

You can check it out here: https://www.siebengiebelwald.de/

You must open it on mobile phone.

The horizontal scroll doesn't work in the third section on mobile but it works on desktop. Why is that?

I used:

```
overflow: auto;
```

along with flexbox.